# 2.79 Projects are textureless in blender 3.4

Tags: mesh, texturing, node-editor, shaders, eevee-render-engine

im trying to use some room from a compilatory of old game files, the thing is, when i load it into blender 3.4, it shows like this:
[image: Blender 3.4]

but, when opening the file in blender 2.79, it shows normally
[image: blender 2.79]

is there like a way to pack the textures or something? or maybe even a tutorial?

(PD: sorry if my english's bad, my native language)

Comment: Hi. You should provide all the relevant details about your problem if you wish to get meaningful help with it.

Comment: The magenta color indicates textures not found.. how were they stored in, or with, the 'old game files' ? What kind of files are those?

Comment: the .blend files are the "old game files" , but they only seem to work correctly on blender version 2.79

Answer (score 1):

If the materials are made with the Blender Render or Blender Game engines, they won't be converted to EEVEE/Cycles and are discarded on opening, only the basic stuff is preserved like Diffuse Color. You need to recreate them in the 2.80+ node system.

You can convert materials from Internal to Cycles inside 2.79- manually or with scripts like https://blenderartists.org/t/materials-specials-conversion/664036 and then you can open it with 2.80+.

I had worked on a script that uses https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender-asset-tracer to do that without 2.79 but did not finish.